# RectTransform's bottom border changes in one resolution but in other doesnt change

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

I made UI auto scale for different resolutions from Unity, and it works well for all of them, but on my phone i have resolution 1080x2400, i tryed it in Unity and borders of object dont strech right, so there appears a gap.

Canvas values

[image]

Video of problem:https://youtu.be/ol_hz5ntY1g

Comment: as a side note your reference resolution seems a bit odd to me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue will be that the aspect ratio of your scroll view is **fixed**

=> the last resolution has a different aspect ratio though so the space isn't filled.

You should rather use a stretched layout for the scroll view in order to fill up the remaining space.

Since your button areas at top and bottom seem to not change sizes dynamically you could simply set your scroll view to something like e.g.

[image]

adjusting those values according to your top and bottom button area heights

Comment: Thank you are right, i changed mods parent object, and now i correctly streched its rect, i couldnt do it with previoes parent object, because its postion wasnt right